# Is it possible to run okio in javascript

Tags: okhttp, okio

I have query about okio , is it possible to run the okio in javascript, is there is any okio package available for javascript ?

i got this query due to this commands in release notes of okio.

> Version 3.0.0-alpha.3¶
> 2021-04-06

> New: Move NodeJsFileSystem into its own module. Having it built-in prevented Okio from working in a browser where there’s no synchronous file system API. This is in the okio-nodefilesystem artifact.

Answer (score 3):

Okio is a Kotlin Multiplatform library and runs in JVM, JS, and native.